# SSIS OLE DB SQL COMMAND - Getting return value from nested stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, ssis, oledbcommand

In SSIS I have an OLE DB SQL Command in my Dataflow that executes a stored procedure which in turn executes a 'nested' stored procedure (`uspMyNestedSP`).  I can't seem to get the RETURN from the nested stored procedure. All SSIS  returns is the int `@RETURN_VALUE` and not the string returned in the stored procedure.

Note, I cannot change `uspMyNestedSP`.

I have tried using `OUTPUT` parameters and setting the `RETURN` to this but all I get back is an empty string.

I need to do it in a OLE DB SQL Command on a row by row basis.

The only other way I can think of is to split the Data flow into two Data Flows and have a SQL TASK do it in between?

Here is the stored procedure:

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspMyMainSP]
    @_EthnicityIOCode NCHAR(20),
    @_EthnicityDescription NVARCHAR(60)
AS
    DECLARE @EthnicityCode NCHAR(8) 
    DECLARE @EthnicityDescription NVARCHAR(60)
    DECLARE @AuditMessage NVARCHAR(128)

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    IF LEN(TRIM(@_EthnicityIOCode)) > 0 AND LEN(TRIM(@_EthnicityDescription)) > 0
    BEGIN
        SELECT  
            @EthnicityCode = ethEthnicityCode,
            @EthnicityDescription = ethDescription
        FROM    
            TC36sp1.dbo.Ethnicity
        WHERE   
            (ethIOCode = @_EthnicityIOCode)

        IF @@ROWCOUNT = 0 
        BEGIN
            --  Insert
            EXEC uspMyNestedSP '*df', @_EthnicityDescription, @_EthnicityIOCode, 1
            SET @AuditMessage = '''' 
        END
        ELSE
            IF @_EthnicityDescription <> @EthnicityDescription
            BEGIN
                -- Update
                EXEC uspMyNestedSP '*df', @_EthnicityDescription, @_EthnicityIOCode, 1
                SET @AuditMessage = ''''
            END

    -- This is what I want to return back to SSIS!...
    RETURN @EthnicityCode 
END
```

The `@EthnicityCode` string is what I want to return. This works fine and returns when run manually in SSMS.

Here is my SQL Command in SSIS:

```
EXEC  ? =uspMyMainSP ?, ?
```

Comment: I don't think OLEDB Command can handle any output. I use a script component for items like this. It is more common practice when you need to know you identity value.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to do it with script component:

```
        string sql = "dbo.uspMyNestedSP";
        using (OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(cstr))
        {
            using (OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", Row.[ColumnName]);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", Row.ColumnName);
                conn.Open();
                string EthnicityCode = cmd.ExecuteScalar();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

1. The `RETURN` can only return `int` so it cannot be used to return a `string` value. Spec:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Try this in SSMS and you'see you'll get this error message:

`Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value 'test    ' to data type int.`

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspMyMainSP]
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @EthnicityCode NCHAR(8) = 'test'

    RETURN @EthnicityCode 
END

GO

EXEC [dbo].[uspMyMainSP]
```

2. Instead of that you can return `SELECT @EthnicityCode as EthnicityCode` as a single record result set and process it down in the data flow.
3. Or use an `OUTPUT` parameter with a little trick: To be able to use `OUTPUT` parameter, you need to map it to an `INPUT` parameter, thus you need a dummy input parameter. Define a dummy string parameter (`Derived Column Name`, set it as `NULL(DT_STR)`)

See here for a more detailed explanation

https://radacad.com/output-parameter-of-stored-procedure-in-ole-db-command-ssis

```
ALTER  PROCEDURE [dbo].[uspMyMainSP]
    @_EthnicityIOCode NCHAR(20),
    @_EthnicityDescription NVARCHAR(60), 
    @EthnicityCode NCHAR(8) OUTPUT   ----added
AS
    -- DECLARE @EthnicityCode NCHAR(8)  ---removed
....



EXEC [dbo].[uspMyMainSP] ?, ?, ? output
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  The above won't work.  I need to clarify that the nested SP 'uspMyNestedSP' is actually returning the string value that I want as an 'Unamed Column' and it's this that I want to capture into my data workflow.  However I cannot change anything in this nested SP.

Comment: Your SP will NOT work in its current condition. You're trying to return `string` via `RETURN`, which only allows numeric return values. Yo uneed to change your SP.

Comment: updated my answer to give you a small example to test and see you can't return string